# Facebook real time updates giving incomplete information on page events

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, real-time-updates

I have subscribed for page subscription for Facebook real time updates with Fields as "feed". When i am creating a new event, the Facebook real time updates sends me a wrong entry. The entry i got as a real time update is below.

```
{
  "entry": [
    {
      "changes": [
        {
          "field": "feed",
          "value": {
            "photo_id": 1128416807216170,
            "**post_id": "902483569809496_1128416807216170"**,
            "sender_name": "Unofficial: Aerospace Demodavid",
            "sender_id": 902483569809496,
            "item": "photo",
            "verb": "edited",
            "link": "https://scontent.ford1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/t31.0-8/13717445_1128416807216170_1696828468485436508_o.jpg",
            "published": 1,
            "created_time": 1470269376
          }
        }
      ],
      "id": "902483569809496",
      "time": 1470269377
    }
  ],
  "object": "page"
}
```

From the above entry, if i query the Graph API for **postid : 902483569809496_1128416807216170** , i get the below JSON response

```
{
  "created_time": "2016-08-04T00:09:36+0000",
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "Like",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/902483569809496/photos/gm.713007008848308/1128416807216170/?type=3"
    },
    {
      "name": "Comment",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/902483569809496/photos/gm.713007008848308/1128416807216170/?type=3"
    },
    {
      "name": "See Friendship",
      "link": "https://m.facebook.com/friendship/902483569809496/713006992181643/"
    }
  ],
  "from": {
    "name": "Unofficial: Aerospace Demodavid",
    "category": "Aerospace/Defense",
    "id": "902483569809496"
  },
  "icon": "https://www.facebook.com/images/icons/photo.gif",
  "is_hidden": false,
  "is_expired": false,
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/902483569809496/photos/gm.713007008848308/1128416807216170/?type=3",
  "object_id": "1128416807216170",
  "picture": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/s130x130/13892116_1128416807216170_1696828468485436508_n.jpg?oh=967e908192fcadc72eae9c11047f87e2&oe=582D6009",
  "privacy": {
    "allow": "",
    "deny": "",
    "description": "",
    "friends": "",
    "value": "EVERYONE"
  },
  "status_type": "added_photos",
  "subscribed": false,
  "to": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "713006992181643",
        "name": "Stevie G Event"
      }
    ]
  },
  "type": "photo",
  "updated_time": "2016-08-04T00:09:36+0000",
  "id": "902483569809496_1128416807216170"
}
```

But the actual thing added here was an event and not a photo. **The id should be 902483569809496_713006992181643 as in the below JSON and not 902483569809496_1128416807216170 which came from the real time update**. Below is the JSON response which i am getting when i query the Graph API manually using the account id without using the real time update information.

```
{
      "id": "902483569809496_713006992181643",
      "from": {
        "name": "Unofficial: Aerospace Demodavid",
        "category": "Aerospace/Defense",
        "id": "902483569809496"
      },
      "story": "Unofficial: Aerospace Demodavid added an event.",
      "story_tags": {
        "0": [
          {
            "id": "902483569809496",
            "name": "Unofficial: Aerospace Demodavid",
            "type": "page",
            "offset": 0,
            "length": 31
          }
        ],
        "41": [
          {
            "id": "713006992181643",
            "name": "Stevie G Event",
            "type": "event",
            "offset": 41,
            "length": 5
          }
        ]
      },
      "picture": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/c39.0.130.130/p130x130/13892116_1128416807216170_1696828468485436508_n.jpg?oh=5adc792bca82e0b110b3d6d98b81feae&oe=581E2680",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/events/713006992181643/",
      "name": "Stevie G Event",
      "caption": "Stevie G Event",
      "description": "Stevie G is the best",
      "icon": "https://www.facebook.com/images/icons/event.gif",
      "actions": [
        {
          "name": "Comment",
          "link": "https://www.facebook.com/902483569809496/posts/713006992181643"
        },
        {
          "name": "Like",
          "link": "https://www.facebook.com/902483569809496/posts/713006992181643"
        }
      ],
      "privacy": {
        "value": "EVERYONE",
        "description": "",
        "friends": "",
        "allow": "",
        "deny": ""
      },
      "type": "event",
      "status_type": "created_event",
      "object_id": "713006992181643",
      "created_time": "2016-08-04T00:09:35+0000",
      "updated_time": "2016-08-04T00:09:35+0000",
      "is_hidden": false,
      "is_expired": false
    }
```

Why is there an inconsistency with the Facebook real time updates sent for an event creation. It treats it as a photo edit and not an event creation.

Please let me know if i am missing something.

Comment: Has your isssue been resolved?? I am facing similar issue with the webhook for events and photos. When user just uploads an image without caption to it or creates an event without uploading photo, it doesn't even get posted to webhook. While if you upload an image to an event then it gets triggered as photo as mentioned above.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/765766950232812/ . This is the bug I had registered. They just replied saying the bug has been fixed. Please let me know if it worked for you. Thanks

Comment: sorry got busy with something else... Going through above link it seemed that now they don't post real time updates for events at all.. ha..  what a solution.. Anyways, another bug related to RTU, I found was, facebook doesn't trigger anything when an image is uploaded without any comment. Here, is the link: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1740620369486641/

Comment: Sadly yes. They do not at the moment